# How could the hormones of an octopus affect an adult man?

Tags: science-based, chemistry, biochemistry, blood, sea-creatures

Let's say the hormones of a Giant Pacific Octopus, 1-and-a-third years old, enter the bloodstream of an adult male. How would or could that affect him?

Comment: What do you mean by oxygen being diffused out of blood? Oxygen is not *dissolved* in blood (mostly), it is carried in the form of oxidized pigment (hemocyanin in the case of octopuses). On the other hand, hormones are indeed carried in solution. And remember that hormones are *signal* carriers; they are present in very small amounts, and to have any effect they need specific receptors. (Think of the radio waves which make a radio play music; those waves are *signals*, carry very little energy and have no effect on devices, such as humans, which are not specifically designed to receive them.)

Comment: Wow, thanks for commenting. Got it, hormones should have no effect on humans. But I just thought that diffusion is how you can get oxygen out of the bloodstream, based on this link I found here: https://www.ck12.org/biology/breathing/lesson/Processes-of-Breathing-MS-LS/. But diffusion isn't how oxygen exits the bloodstream? I'm trying to figure out a process to extract oxygen from blood, could you please tell me how this works?

Comment: I didn't say that the hormones of an octopus will have no effect on humans; I suggest we wait for someone with medical background and an interest in cephalopods. But I would be surprised in there is any effect to be expected, and *very* surprised if any effect is not of very short duration.

Comment: Okay, thanks AlexP.

Comment: *"Diffusion":* it's more complicated, and I don't know how exactly it works for the blue hemocyanin of cephalopods. In humans with their red hemoglobin, it works as follows. [Hemoglobin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemoglobin) can take two shapes, one called tense (T) and one called relaxed (R). The switch from T to R and vice-versa depends on the chemical environment. In the lungs, hemoglobin is made to take the R form, which binds the oxygen coming by diffusion from the air. When it reaches the tissues it is made to take the T form, which releases the bound oxygen which then diffuses out.

Comment: Your query, as written, is way too broad.  Which octopus hormone would you like to focus on?  One that is shared with humans or one that is not?  Please review the [help] and [tour] so you can get a better idea how to formulate questions here!

Comment: How complicated would a device simulating that have to be? It does sound more complicated than I thought.

Comment: @elemtilas The Giant Pacific Octopus. Sorry, that's the octopus I always default to when I hear "octopus." I don't know what you mean by "shared with humans." (Edit) Oh, and I don't know which hormone to focus on. Just the one that would cause the most prominent effect if that's okay.

Comment: These questions seem unrelated.  We have a one question per question policy on Stack Exchange.  In particular, this seems important because if you isolate the Octopus hormones and inject them in the humans, the question about oxygen is irrelevant.  If you're injecting the octopus blood raw into the human, there's a whole host of other effects that will appear as the body combats this invading mass.

Comment: Oh yeah, I think I've already heard about dangers associated with Xenotransplantation. If I'm correct, it would be the same dangers as giving someone the wrong blood type. What I was trying to ask was if the hormones itself when isolated would have any effect on humans.

Comment: So I'll go ahead and delete " Would it be dangerous? Would it just be weird? Would it have no effect?

And one more thing. I'm assuming that if oxygen is diffused out of an octopus's bloodstream, all the hormones would be, too. Is that at all true?" I guess, since it's irrelevant you say.

Comment: Oh, I'll also go ahead and specify that it's a Giant Pacific Octopus within the post itself.

Comment: And, lastly, I've created this new Question for what I've removed from my question here: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/148355/if-oxygen-is-extracted-from-blood-would-the-process-cause-any-hormones-within-i.

Comment: Well, Luke, it looks like you need to do some homework!  It literally took Google 0.67 seconds to return results for a variety of reproductive & stress hormones that are common to invertebrates and vertebrates. If you don't know what hormone to focus on, then you are basically trawling for ideas.  This is a no-no on Stack Exchange in general.  Broad questions are also a no-no.  Please do some basic research and then come up with a focused question!

Comment: Sorry, I had assumed that hormones were always unique to any given animal and didn't think that they might share the same ones. And I was mostly concerned with the health of the man, rather than the possible perceivably-cool effects, not trawling for ideas, rather. Both today and yesterday I had done *plenty* of research on octopuses, and had gotten stuck on a question by now. I had already researched "octopus hormones," but they had taken me to links that were, for one thing, a bit beyond my head, and for another, already not having a thing to do with humans when I search for them.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Luke. Please note that you can notify one user per comment using the '@<username>' syntax.

Comment: @Frostfyre well thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The main effect I could see is the human suffering a severe allergic reaction as the alien proteins entered the bloodstream and then into the body. Not a itchy skin rash type reaction but more like anaphylactic shock or major organs shutting down type of reaction.

It is tricky enough doing blood transfusions between human beings unless you have carefully matched the donor to the receiver or are using "universal donor" O- blood. Trying to do that with a completely different species is just madness.

Comment: Got it, so hormones themselves injected into the bloodstream would be treated as any xenotransplantation or other incompatible blood type would? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Love, and milk.**

Many hormones are evolutionarily very ancient.  One is **oxytocin**.

http://www.yourhormones.info/hormones/oxytocin/

> In the brain, oxytocin acts as a chemical messenger and has been shown
>   to be important in human behaviours including sexual arousal,
>   recognition, trust, anxiety and mother–infant bonding. As a result,
>   oxytocin has been called the 'love hormone' or 'cuddle chemical'.

from https://www.azula.com/female-octopuses-special-super-momhormone-2476361777.html

> Cephalopods have their own kind of oxytocin, appropriately called
>   cephalotocin. The last common ancestor of octopuses and humans was a
>   worm-like creature that lived as far back as 750 million years ago.
>   This suggests that motherly love—or something like it—might be
>   unimaginably ancient.

I here assert that cephalotocin is structurally similar to human oxytocin, but several thousand times more potent to humans that our native hormone is.  Exposure of a human to cephalotocin therefore produces overwhelming feelings of bonding, sexual arousal, and closeness as well as failure to lay down short term memories, orgasm-like uterine contractions and production of milk.